# How to use the phase "as opposed to"?

Tags: grammar, construction

As the title states, in what circumstance should i use *"as opposed to"*?
Can i use "vice versa" in some context instead?

Comment: Hi, Roger, just dropping in as part of the community review. It would be better if for all of us involved if we had some example sentences to work with. Meanwhile, thanks for your question and welcome to the English Language Learners Stack Exchange.

Comment: And just off the top of my head, I would say no, the two are not interchangeable, but who knows, maybe there is an example somewhere where it works. Mostly because on the whole, "as opposed to" talks about differences as opposed to "vice versa," which talks about similarities, so it's hard to think of an example where one could work and vice versa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "as opposed to" mean?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58968/what-does-as-opposed-to-mean). I know it's not a total duplicate, but had just wanted to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Roger, welcome to ELL. Generally, we prefer people to do a bit of research before posting a question. In this case, you could look up the two expressions in a good dictionary, like this one: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/opposed?q=as+opposed+to. If your research doesn't find the information that you require, please edit your question to explain what specifically you don't understand, and provide links to your research.

Answer (score 2):

*As opposed to* is used to underline difference or radical distinction in something:

> I have done my homework **as opposed to** you[, *who have not]*!

Possible synonym is *as distinct from*, but whereas the former implies contraposition, the latter means just difference. Compare:

> John lives on the 3rd floor  **as distinct from** Peter, who lives on the
>   2nd.

*Vice versa* means in reverse order, conversely and has different meaning:

> I don't like him, and vice versa.

which means the speaker doesn't like someone and they don't like the speaker, either.

Comment: I would almost add "as opposed to you, *who have not*" in the example sentence just to keep the construction similar. Not a grammatical comment, more a stylistic one (same as your second example sentence).

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I've added it in parentheses.

Comment: Cool! Just to be a stickler, though, if the OP does choose to include "who have not," he would need a comma after "you." Heh, which means, yes, you should have a comma in your second sentence after "Peter" as well :O :D.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Can you edit answers, by the way? ;)

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure. In the past, there had been a limit on the number of characters I had to edit in order to submit one, so for minor edits like these, I stopped making them. On the other hand, I had actually only meant my initial comment in passing since it was about style, which may vary from person to person. It wasn't until you had edited the answer that I had been (pleasantly) surprised :D.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I see. Let's hope the OP will find the results of our common effort useful lol

Answer (score 2):

Here are the definitions from the Oxford Dictionary:

[as opposed to](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/as_opposed_to): Distinguished from or in contrast with.

> We are talking about a **theoretical** situation, as opposed to an **actual** one.

[vice versa](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vice_versa): With the main items in the preceding statement the other way round.

> I know everything about him, and vice versa - *(he also knows everything about me)*

The former is used to contrast two things, and the other is a shorthand way of saying that one thing also works the other way round.